# Is there a high-level inter-process communications API that is implemented in both C++ and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, sockets, network-programming, websocket

I am working on app where I need to pass messages between a C++ application and a Javascript web app.

Certainly I could write sockets code myself in either language and I have done this in the past when necessary.

What I would really like is a higher-level message posting or message queueing API that does a lot of the work for me.  Does anyone know of such an API?

I have looked at ICE, and it doesn't appear to have Javascript bindings.  I have also looked at Boost message queue, but it only caters for the C++ side of things.  If necessary I might roll my own Javascript bindings for either of these technologies.

UPDATE: Sorry should have mentioned this before, I want to run this in a browser.

To give a more complete story what I want is a simple browser-based app that is used to configure and display logging for a C++ application.

I know there are other ways of doing this, but I am specifically interested in a high-level library in both C++ and browser-based Javascript that builds a message queue ontop of the sockets API (if there isn't one then I might consider implementing it myself and writing up a code project article).

ALSO: I'm not bothered about portability in terms of the web browser.  Eg if there is a high-level IPC Javascript library that only works in Chrome, I'll be happy with that.

Comment: Is it in browser, or server side js? What environment?

Comment: Your choices are basically JSON/HTTP, XML/HTTP, or something using WebSockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution that meets my needs. It isn't exactly perfect but I think it works well enough.

Some people suggested using HTTP and ajax.  That turned out to be a useful idea and after some prototyping I think it solves my rather basic needs.

To be more specific I am using the Mongoose HTTP server embedded in my C++ application and I am using the jQuery ajax function to pull data from the server.  The jQuery client polls the server continously for new data, not particularly efficient but I think it will do the job good enough for me.

Once my implementation is complete I'll write an article explaining how to do this in detail and then I'll update this answer.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I have written an article about the project I was talking about in this question/answer. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448756/Introducing-Investigo-Using-a-Proxy-DLL-and-embedd

Answer (score 4):

To simply answer your question: No, there is no IPC implemented in ECMAscript out of the box.

But you actually answered you question already. If you try to communicate with Javascript that runs in a browser, you indeed should use (web-)sockets connections to pipe date in either direction. Of course you could write a simple HTTP server in C++, but I guess that is overkill  and does not have the capabilitys of bi-directional sockets.

It's still some work to implement a web-socket connection in C++ from the scratch (the specs were in flux for a long time), but I guess there are some librarys out already.

If you're trying to communicate with *node.js*, this is an almost trivial task using real sockets/pipes.

Comment: Isn't websockets (a method of IPC) included (at least in some browsers) out of the box?

Comment: How does XMLHttpRequest not satisfy the definition of IPC? It's even a good, obvious basis for an RPC interface.

Comment: @jAndy Is it still some work to implement web-sockets in C++ from scratch? Are there any resources you recommend and would be useful in achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

With JavaScript I assume that you are running it in a browser? In this case your C++ application needs to provide a webserver and some kind of JSON based webservice that you can call. On the JavaScript side you just use AJAX to communicate with that webservice.

An alternative would be websockets which might be a little harder to implement on the C++ side though.

Comment: Yep running it in browser.  Web sockets is what I am thinking I'll be using in the Javascript.

Comment: That might become tricky. Depending on what browser versions you want to support you also need to implement fallbacks since not all of them  have full websocket support. Basically you'll need http://socket.io but for C++ instead of NodeJS. The webservice will work everywhere and also with clients other than JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You could try DBus, it has very simple mechanism to define, query and use interfaces, and there are some components for XPCOM and webkit based browsers (for example http://sandbox.movial.com/wiki/index.php/Browser_DBus_Bridge and http://code.google.com/p/v8-dbus/). Also DBus is opensource and cross platform.

Comment: Thanks. That looks interesting, I'll look into it.

Comment: I don't think this will do what he wants. I think he wants the web app to talk to applications on his server, not applications on the same local machine as the browser. This will only work if the browser and the C++ app are on the same machine. (DBus is a local communication scheme.)

Answer (score 0):

For a server side or non-browser implementation how about named pipes?

Yes it's vintage technology and the usage depends which OS you use, but as long as your server side js environment has ability to read and write files it may work, and it fits the description 'high-level' inter-process communication.

Comment: Aha, it's browser based, per the update, so my answer doesn't apply.